# GemBox WPF dependency does not work on App Service Azure deployment

Tags: wpf, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.0, gembox-document

I developed a test .NET Core Web App to which I added the .doc to .pdf conversion tool GemBox.

Their documentation for Azure deployment combined with .NET Core is limited to non-existing and their support guys could not help me with a clear solution either.

The error I get:

> HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies Common
>   solutions to this issue: The specified version of
>   Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.

I tracked down the problem to the following issue: 
GemBox.Document for .NET Core 3.0 uses WPF.
Is it possible that App Service added a limited support for WPF?

Thanks,
Lorena

Answer (score 0):

The latest released version of GemBox.Document have cross-platform support for saving to PDF which doesn't have a WPF dependency, see the [release post](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/news/support-for-pdf-on-linux-macos) or the [ASP.NET Core](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/asp-net-core-create-word-docx-pdf/5601) example.

So, you can now use GemBox.Document on Azure services, such as App Service, Azure Functions, etc. without any issue.